# ValueError: could not convert string to float: (in python)

Tags: python

'this is my code'

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

URL = 'https://www.amazon.de/dp/B07KHKSZCJ?pf_rd_r=S1K975F9036B2X99PTNT&pf_rd_p=d1c766cf-ac59-4683-9885-c21368aa4f05'

headers = {"User-Agent": 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/81.0.4044.129 Safari/537.36 OPR/68.0.3618.112'}



page = requests.get(URL, headers=headers)

soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, "html.parser")

title = soup.find(id="productTitle").get_text()
price = soup.find(id="priceblock_ourprice").get_text()
converted_price = float(price[0:5])

if (converted_price > 100):
    print(title)
    print(price)
```

'it gives me this error can some one help: ValueError: could not convert string to float: '

Comment: Check the price column the value which you parsing is not coming correct means not a float value so instead of converting to float first print as-is and identify the row which creating the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, because it is '218,9' and not '218.9'. You should change the error line like this:

```py
converted_price = float(price[0:3] + '.' + price[4])
```

Comment: For values unknown length try `float(price.replace(',', '.'))`

Answer (score 0):

```
def price_check():
title = soup.find(id="productTitle").text
pg = soup.find(id="priceblock_ourprice").text
covt_pr=float(pg[0:9])
#covt_pr=float(pg.replace('₹\xa0' , '').replace(',', '.').replace('5.999.00', '5.999'))
print(title.strip())
print(covt_pr)
#if (covt_pr > 5.500):
    #send_mail()
```

price_check()

ok if i run this then i am getting an error *ValueError: could not convert string to float: '₹\xa05,999.0'* *the symbol at the start is the currency symbol*....now, replace *₹\xa0* this with an empty string "" ...or just use the code below

```
    covt_pr=float(pg.replace('₹\xa0' , '').replace(',', '.').replace('5.999.00', '5.999'))
```

go through the above code you'll know the variables that i used and would probably solve it...xd

```
def price_check():
title = soup.find(id="productTitle").text
pg = soup.find(id="priceblock_ourprice").text
covt_pr=float(pg.replace('₹\xa0' , '').replace(',', '.').replace('5.999.00', '5.999'))
print(title.strip())
print(covt_pr)
if (covt_pr > 5.500):
    send_mail()
```

price_check()

OUTPUT: JBL Tune 750BTNC Over-Ear Wireless Active Noise-Cancelling Headphones with 15 Hours Playtime (Black)
5.999
email has been sent to the requested mail..!
IT WORKS.